# Vue Nuxt I18n , the message properties it's not reflect directly when add new one or edit exist property

Tags: vuejs2, nuxt.js, nuxt-i18n

i have Nuxt project, when i try to add or edit message property it's not reflect direct, i should terminate the app and re-run it to see the results.

i followed the Nuxt Documentation and applied every single step

Comment: Mind sharing more details about your configuration? Providing a [repro] or any useful context, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit your `nuxt.config.js` modules to look like this

```js
modules: [
  [
    "@nuxtjs/i18n",
    {
      locales: [{ code: "en", name: "en-US", file: "en.json" }],
      langDir: "locales/"
    }
  ],
]
```

assuming your strings file is called `en.json` and it's inside `locales/` like `locales/en.json`

Comment: Quite a duplicate if I'm not mistaken, should only have the definition of the module once.

Comment: @kissu ah yes, my bad .. I copied it from the git log and added both the deleted and the added lines 

Comment: yes i fixed it like your anwer , in addition to add lazy:true to the config